# Get dput data assigned to variable

Tags: r

When I try to assign dput to object, it assigns and then prints the values below. It should ne happen.It should just pass to the object

```
get_ls <- dput(head(iris))
structure(list(Sepal.Length = c(5.1, 4.9, 4.7, 4.6, 5, 5.4), 
    Sepal.Width = c(3.5, 3, 3.2, 3.1, 3.6, 3.9), Petal.Length = c(1.4, 
    1.4, 1.3, 1.5, 1.4, 1.7), Petal.Width = c(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 
    0.2, 0.2, 0.4), Species = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L), .Label = c("setosa", "versicolor", "virginica"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Expected output

```
get_ls <- dput(head(iris))
get_ls
structure(list(Sepal.Length = c(5.1, 4.9, 4.7, 4.6, 5, 5.4), 
    Sepal.Width = c(3.5, 3, 3.2, 3.1, 3.6, 3.9), Petal.Length = c(1.4, 
    1.4, 1.3, 1.5, 1.4, 1.7), Petal.Width = c(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 
    0.2, 0.2, 0.4), Species = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L), .Label = c("setosa", "versicolor", "virginica"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Why would you want to assign the output of ``dput`` to an object?

Comment: The plan is to convert this dput to something else in the code later on

Comment: Out of curiosity, I'll ask the same question as @user438383, why convert to dput? I mean why not just use in your example ```get_ls<-head(iris)```. I'm guessing you are using something specific in the dput output?

Comment: Yeah right. It is a long list. The only way to get that is through dput

Comment: From the online doc for `dput`: "Value For dput, the first argument invisibly.".  So `dput` is doing what it should, but not what you want.  `sink()` may allow you to do what you want.  But I concur with the other commenters: it's difficult to think of scenario in which what you want to do is sensible, let alone optimal.

Comment: It's still not clear to me what you want the class of the expected output to be. Are you trying to create a character value (a string)? An unevaluated expression? Can you show an example of what you are trying to do with this output so it's clear why you think a `dput` is necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a new function to extract the call printed by `dput()`.

```r
dput.call <- function(x) {
  parse(text = capture.output(dput(x)))[[1]]
}

get_ls <- dput.call(head(iris))
get_ls
# structure(list(Sepal.Length = c(5.1, 4.9, 4.7, 4.6, 5, 5.4), 
#     Sepal.Width = c(3.5, 3, 3.2, 3.1, 3.6, 3.9), Petal.Length = c(1.4, 
#         1.4, 1.3, 1.5, 1.4, 1.7), Petal.Width = c(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 
#         0.2, 0.2, 0.4), Species = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
#         1L, 1L), .Label = c("setosa", "versicolor", "virginica"), 
#         class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

class(get_ls)
# [1] "call"
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are after:

```r
con <- file() # new connect
dput(mtcars, con) # dump the dput in the connection
readLines(con) # read it as a vector
```